# Python: How do you change a scripts location of execution in vscode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Running **print({os.getcwd})** reveals the location where a script is being executed from. In my case, this is happening from outside the directory where my .py and .txt files are saved, which means I have to use absolute paths in order for my code to not return a "FileNotFoundError".

How do I specify the path where python3 scripts are executed in visual studio code, to avoid using absolute paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
os.chdir(path)
```

to **really change** the working directory

or

```
sys.path.append(path)
```

to just add another path you can import from.